# Upload Blob from Stream, with options but without overwriting

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I need to upload a Blob given a Stream. In addition I want to set BlobUploadOptions and not overwrite any existing blob. I couldn't find a matching overload for `UploadAsync` though. There's

- `UploadAsync(System.IO.Stream content, Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models.BlobUploadOptions options, [System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken = null]` missing the overwrite boolean
- `UploadAsync(System.IO.Stream content, [bool overwrite = False], [System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken = null])` having the overwrite boolean, but missing the BlobUploadOptions

So, what's the correct way for my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the documentation for [`UploadAsync(Stream, BlobUploadOptions, CancellationToken)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobclient.uploadasync?view=azure-dotnet#azure-storage-blobs-blobclient-uploadasync(system-io-stream-azure-storage-blobs-models-blobuploadoptions-system-threading-cancellationtoken)), you can use access conditions to prevent overwriting the blob.

[image]

Reading the documentation about conditional headers [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/specifying-conditional-headers-for-blob-service-operations), what you would want to do is use [`IfNoneMatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.matchconditions.ifnonematch?view=azure-dotnet#azure-matchconditions-ifnonematch) access condition and specify the value as `*` to fail the operation if blob exists.

[image]